# Show spinner while Sharrre buttons load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wanting to use Sharrre jQuery plugin for sharing a page on my website. However, the buttons take a second or two to load, and load one-at-a-time, each one popping up in a line.

It's an unfortunate effect. I'd rather hide the contents of the div until all the buttons are loaded, instead showing a spinner or some other appropriate distraction.

I don't know how to detect when the sharrre plugin has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the documentation and saw the render method which would run only when it's done rendering. (I am assuming rendering would cover loading images too).

You can try something like this

```
$('#share').sharrre({
   share: {
     googlePlus: true,
     facebook: true,
     twitter: true
   },
   url: 'http://sharrre.com/'
   render: function() {$('i.spinner').remove()}
 });
```

Or like you were asking for it you can make the container div transparent initially and set to opacity to 1 inside render method.